# How to display a post(by id) along with css in a page?

Tags: wp-query, shortcode, templates

I am curious if it's possible to get a post content along with its CSS (say if button background color is green on the post) and display it a page?

I am able to get the content but the CSS are not coming up. I tried with page builder elementor. I created a post ( button with green background) but when I display it on a page it shows the button but without green background

Basically creating a template and displaying it on some other page.

Comment: That's not really how CSS works. If you want certain CSS to apply to buttons regardless of page, you need to write your CSS that way. If your CSS is page-specific then it's not going to apply to another page no matter what you do.

Comment: @JacobPeattie thanks for clearing